# lxml error when running sugiyama.py on Mac

Tags: python, pip, lxml, conda, flow-project

Recently I want to try flow-project on Mac, and after installing all requirements and trying to run python examples/sumo/sugiyama.py, I got an error as stated below. Could you please help me to solve it?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "examples/sumo/sugiyama.py", line 7, in <module>
    from flow.core.experiment import Experiment
  File "/Users/voanhkha/Desktop/flow/flow/core/experiment.py", line 9, in <module>
    from flow.core.util import emission_to_csv
  File "/Users/voanhkha/Desktop/flow/flow/core/util.py", line 6, in <module>
    from lxml import etree
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/voanhkha/anaconda3/envs/flow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/lxml/etree.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/voanhkha/anaconda3/envs/flow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/lxml/etree.cpython-36m-darwin.so: unknown file type, first eight bytes: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
    /Users/voanhkha/anaconda3/envs/flow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/lxml/etree.cpython-36m-darwin.so: unknown file type, first eight bytes: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and uninstalled the `conda` version of `lxml` and install it again with `pip`.

```
conda uninstall lxml
pip install lxml
```